# Translation help (French): "Monoïde cycliste"

Tags: soft-question, monoid, translation-request

I am reading this [paper](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Mps/Travaux/A/1981-2KazhdanAsterisque.pdf), and in section 4, they define the "monoïde cycliste" to be the quotient of the free monoid on two generators, $\{\alpha,\beta\}^*$, by the relations $\alpha\alpha\beta \sim \alpha \beta \alpha$ and $\beta \alpha\beta \sim \alpha\beta\beta$.

I am unsure how to translate "monoïde cycliste." I was first tempted to say "cyclic monoid," but at the end of the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Examples), we see that a cyclic monoid is the analogue of a cyclic group, which happens to be "groupe cyclique," not "groupe cycliste." Does anyone know a good way to translate "cycliste"? Maybe "cyclist monoid"? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the humour of (the late) Alain Lascoux, and Marco Schützenberger. In French a cycliste is one who rides a bicycle, and as an adjective it means in relation to (the sport of) riding bicycles. Since that monoid has two generators, they no doubt found the allusion to bicycles appropriate. It would seem to me there is no really pressing need to give the two-letter instance of the plactic monoid a special name, but as a translation "cyclist monoid" is as good as any. As an alternative option I could propose "bicyclic monoid", although that could possibly be confused with the *free* monoid with two generators.

Comment: Thanks very much, I was wondering myself why they felt it necessary to name this particular structure. On the topic of humor, could you shed some light on this particular sentence in section 11? "On représente usuellement une partition par un diagramme, qui, hors le Royaume Uni et ses dépendances, consiste en un empilement de boîtes rectifié à gauche." Is this a pun on "partition" or something?

Comment: @blf That's not a joke, it is just a description of how conventions for drawing partitions differ.

Comment: @mt_ Ah, my mistake, I wasn't aware of the convention difference.

Comment: @marc-van-leeuwen The bicyclic monoid is another famous monoid in semigroup theory. It is the quotient of the free monoid on two generators $\{a, b\}^*$ by the relation $ab = 1$. This monoid was of course very well known to Schützenberger.

Comment: @blf There is indeed a joke in your quote. "hors le Royaume Uni et ses dépendances" refers to "rectifié à **gauche**". Since people drive on the left in the UK, you may assume that for them, a partition is "un empilement de boîtes rectifié à **droite**". Well, that's the spirit of the pun...

Comment: @J.-E I don't really think this can be it. UK partitions aren't rectifié à droite, rather they are like French ones reflected in the "x-axis"

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Thanks for pointing out the true confusion that "bicyclic monoid" would cause. About the humour in the Young diagram citation, I think it is mainly in the implicit and grotesque accusation of everyone not following their convention to belong to a UK dependency.